# jquery use html () after setting the content, how to make the new elements event and original elements bind the same event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="1">
<div>
<ul>
<li><button id="button">a</button></li>
<li><span>1</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="2">
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#button").live("click",function(){
var s = Number($(this).parents("ul").find("span").text());
$(this).parents("ul").find("span").text(s+1);
$("#2 li").html($("#1 li").html());
});
```

The problem is that when I click on the button , span's number add number 1 and DIV#2 set up a new button , how can i add DIV#1 span number when i click DIV#2 new , I means how this function can find the right parents and span?

[here is DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xavv/2/)

i want to add number 1 when i click new button ,that's all,thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that an `id` can't be just a number? It has to start with a letter

Answer (score 0):

You can check changed [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xavv/3/).

```
$("#button").live("click",function(){        
    var span = $('#1 span');
    span.html(Number(span.html())+1);    
    $("#2 li").html($("#1 li").html());
});
```

Comment: thank you ,but it just a example,i will use parents() and find() in my project.so i can Adapt to complex situations and find the elements

Comment: I think you should use classes for such purposes that would make your job easier.